# How to use $language array in region--header.tpl.php

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am using [Language Switcher Dropdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown) module for language selection.

Successfully implemented this module and also get `$language` array properly in `page.tpl.php` file based on language selection.

But I am not able to get `$language` array in `region--header.tpl.php` file.

So how can I use this array in region files ?

Answer (score 1):

`$language;` is a global variable in drupal 7. You can get this variable in `region--header.tpl.php` as shown below:

```
global $language;
```